# FileMaker Pro 9: Automate script to run daily? [Windows XP]

Tags: export, filemaker

I wrote a script in FileMaker Pro 9 to export some records to a .tab file, and I need this script to run daily. I am running Windows XP. I haven't found any function in FM to take care of this - is there a way to run it from the command line? I know that I could set something like that up with Scheduler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd create a second FileMaker file which runs a script on Open which does the following:

```
Open File [Your Other File]
Perform Script [Export Script]
Close File [Current File]
Exit Application
```

And then set that file to be scheduled by Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Sounds great! I'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks a lot, man.

Comment: Glad it works for you, I use it in a few places for automated imports/exports.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember which version of FileMaker it was introduced with, but I think it was either 10 or 11, but there's a script step called "Install OnTimer Script" that can execute a script after a certain period of time, measured in seconds. You might also check into that.

http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/scripts_ref1.36.16.html

Comment: Thanks, but that won't quite work for what I'm going for. I've got a whole string of processes that I need to automate. The the FileMaker file is going to be opened from a batch file, and things need to happen after that. Basically, I'm working on making a FileMaker export, parsing the output and injecting HTML where necessary, and uploading the result to my company's website - with one click. I'll keep this function in mind, though, as it may prove to come in handy later.