# FileMaker Task Automation

Tags: filemaker

I'd like to automate several FileMaker tasks using Windows Task Scheduler. It looks like step scripts are the way to go, but I'm not sure. I'd like to run tasks, say exporting for example, several times per day, but WITHOUT opening the FileMaker GUI. Is that possible? Any tips you have would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you mean by "*opening the FileMaker GUI*". Nothing can be done in FileMaker without having a file open - but a file can be opened hidden and a window can be hidden or positioned off-screen.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220952/filemaker-pro-9-automate-script-to-run-daily-windows-xp/5221608

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to initiate a Filemaker script using a schedule server script with Filemaker Server. However, if the database is not hosted using Filemaker server, or not open using Filemaker Pro (sounds like your situation), then there is no active engine able to actually perform the calculations (script steps, etc). The database has to be running somewhere to initiate and perform any scripts.

If the database is hosted using Filemaker Server then it is pretty easy to setup a scheduled script that will run at a designated time. If you don't have a license of Filemaker Server some Filemaker cloud hosting providers have monthly plans that are relatively cheap ($20/month with unlimited connections), and they'll work with you to setup a scheduled script (for free).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to automate FileMaker tasks is to use FileMaker Server which has scheduled scripts. Of course it is more expensive than standalone version of FileMaker Pro.

If you automate tasks on a local FileMaker file, you can not avoid starting FileMaker and opening the file.

FileMaker has a limited support for VBScript, you can run FileMaker, open file and run a FileMaker Script from VBScript and add that script to Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

This is not preferable way, but if you have no other option, this may be handy.

1. in Task Scheduler, Create a task
2. on Action tab, choose 
   ["Start Program"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqtL3.jpg)
3. on the next screen, point to FileMaker Pro exe file, typically it is in C:\Program Files\Filemaker Pro\FileMaker.exe
4. Add argument: 
   "fmp://hostName/fileName.fmp12?script=scriptName&param=optionalScriptParameters"
   please read more here http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/en/html/sharing_data.16.7.html about url schema. This will vary depending on whether you are hosting your file on FileMaker Server or opening it locally.
   **Note:** avoid having spaces or special characters in script name.
5. Save the task. Reopen task properties and save your windows account credentials, so that the task may run without you having to login.
6. either save FileMaker login credentials upon login (if your FM version allows), or pass credentials through fmp url (as described in the link above), or go to FileMaker file options, and use credentials in "Log in using": (which is not secure and not recommended).

I am using this method to automatically send emails with PDF attachments, since FileMaker server does not let you Export Records as PDF (not until v.16) on server scripts.